# Django Permissions with CustomUser

Tags: python, django, django-views, permissions

I'm trying to implement class Based views with permissions and they do not seem to connect, although I believe I strictly followed Django User's guide.
First: set up of a Custom User model, based on Proxies, in accounts.models

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
 some_fields...
```

Then, I created a Manager:

```
class EmployeeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(status_type=CustomUser.StatusType.EMPLOYEE)
```

Followed by the type of profile:

```
class Employee(CustomUser):
    objects = EmployeeManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        permissions = [("communities.view_region", "Can view region")]
```

Where I set a permission, make the migrations and migrate.
After, I create the view:

```
import communities.models as comms

class RegionsListView(ListView):
    model = comms.Region
```

Then, configuration of the url and its view:

```
rom django.urls import path, include
import communities.views as views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

app_name = 'communities'

urlpatterns = [
    path("regions/list/", permission_required("communities.view_region")(views.RegionsListView.as_view()))
```

Then I log in as an employee and I get an error 403 when calling this url.

What did I miss ?
Remarks:

- using `permission_required = 'communities.view_region'` in the view.py file produces the same result.
- when logging as a superuser, I get of course the right page.

Comment: I suspect that your employee does not have a view_region permission. :)

Comment: Does it mean that when I call the Permission model, there is something wrong ?


```>>> content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Employee, for_concrete_model=False)```
```>>> employee_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)```
```>>> [p.codename for p in employee_permissions]```
```['add_employee', 'change_employee', 'communities.view_region', 'delete_employee', 'view_employee', 'view_list_regions']```

Because the permission is displayed...  I'm totally puzzled.

Comment: You show the permissions that employee can POTENTIALLY have. However, before the newly created employee will be able to use those permissions, you need to GRANT them first. My guess is that you forgot to grant permissions to the newly created employee, and I would check the actual permissions of the employee account that you are using for testing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I could go forward and set a group to a user through the admin interface.
However, how could I reach the same result, when creating a user using a custom view and template ? 
If I create a "group" field in a one-to-many relations to Group, it takes it into account, however it does implement the group and I have to do it again in the admin Page...

Comment: 1) Groups link to users using ManyToMany relationship, and I believe that AbstractUser model is linked to Django Group model, and there is no need to do something on your own. 2) User is creation is defined in UserManager, the example is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example, and you could define here a method , lets say, create_employee or re-define create_user method.

Comment: You certainly are right. The CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin) class rejects a direct relation to class Group as it is a Many-to-Many relation.
For sure, I should have built my User model base on AbstractBasedUser as depicted in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement the permissions, it had to be done programmatically, while creating a new user.
In the workflow,

- the new User gets an activation e-mail with a unique link,
- the click gives him access to the website and he is required to immediately change his password,
- the validation implements the permission (in this case, a Group)

Here is the code.

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # Attributes to a user a group depending on his status.
            user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name=user.status_type))
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Your PWD has been changed')
            return redirect('change_password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please Correct the Error')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', {'form': form})
```